# SVM/Linear Regression after PCA and making up numbers

Tags: r, regression, pca, svm

I recently saw an answer on Stackoverflow where a person tried to run a linear regression after doing PCA but the answerer suggested making up the dependent variable. Is this something that's acceptable? Are there other ways of applying SVM/Linear Regression after PCA.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805149/how-to-fit-a-linear-regression-model-with-two-principal-components-in-r

Comment: Look into Principal Components Regression (PCR) if you are looking for a PCA/regression one-two punch.

Comment: Are you asking if it's acceptable to run linear regression on PCA, or to make up data? If 1) yes, this is called principal component regression. If 2) it looks like that SO post generated a synthetic dataset just as an example to demonstrate the regression method.

Comment: @user20160 I'm asking if it's acceptable to make up a dependent variable to conduct SVM/linear regression.

Comment: It depends on the purpose. Do you have something particular in mind?

Comment: @user20160 I want use a SVM after applying PCA. I'm not sure how to begin. Is making up data the only way?

Comment: I mean, what are you hoping to get out of your experiment (on synthetic data or otherwise)?

Comment: @user20160 I'm not looking to do prediction, just to find some correlations between data and making up data seems detrimental.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail exactly what the situation is and what you're trying to do?